# Overlapping content hides footer links on certain help pages

Tags: bug, design

On the [advanced editing help page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help), scrolling to the bottom of the page can cause the sidebar to overlap the footer links and make them inaccessible.

Here's a screencap:

[image]

Comment: I can't tell what the problem you're referring to is, and the image is too small to tell. Could you explain more explicitly what link is hidden, and in what page/situation?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I *think* they're referring to the sidebar on the right overrunning the links in the bottom right.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: Looks to me like http://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help. If you make a very vertically short window, the sidebar hovers over the links to other network sites in the footer.

Comment: @alexwlchan: yes exactly , edited the post.

Comment: In can confirm it happens here too (Chrome v35 on Win7) when the window height is small, and that it also happens on StackOverflow.com and 3 other SE sites I checked. Perhaps it should be moved to Meta.SE.